# No devuelve el string

Tags: javascript, jquery

*Tengo un **input** en el que pondré la palabra*

> 'Party: '

```js
function go() {
  var c = document.getElementById("mm");
  var part = "Party: ";
  var partC = part.fontcolor("black");
  var f = c.value = partC;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="goes" onclick="go()">
<input type="text" id="mm">
```

*El problema es que **me aparece la estructura** del **font** y no solo la string, cuál es el problema?*

**Edito:** Sí coloco

> var f = c.value = part;

Saldrá

> 'party'

, pero sin el color cambiado.

**SEGUNDA EDICIÓN: No quiero aplicarle a todo el valor solo a la string, este es el código completo:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#gParty').on("click", function(){
        var c = document.getElementById("partyCode");
        var part = "Party: ";
        var partC = part.fontcolor("black");
        var d = c.value = partC+selectedServer;
        var e = c.style.textAlign = 'center';
        var f = c.style.color = "red";
        var p = c.style.fontFamily = "Ubuntu";
        var i = c.style.fontSize = "larger";
        console.log(c);



    }
```

Comment: Mira la edición

Comment: disculpa lois6b, no he podido probarlo por mi pc, en un ratillo lo haré , gracias :)

Answer (score 6):

<strike>Poniendo `.style.color` para el color modificas la propiedad `css` del elemento. `Color` es el color de la fuente.</strike>

Y `.value`  para el atributo `value` del `input`

---

<sub>Nota: Puse rojo para que se vea el cambio</sub>

Segun la nueva edicion:

No puedes poner un cacho de un `input type text` de una manera y otro cacho de otra

Para eso usa un `div` con `contentEditable="true"` para poder escribir como si fuera un input.

---

Puse una comprobacion para que si ya tiene ese `font`, no añada más. Y para que si has escrito algo, te lo ponga delante de ese texto.

```js
function go() {
  var c = document.getElementById("mm");
  var part = "Party: ";
  var partC = "red"; //"black"

  var text = c.innerHTML;
  if (!text.includes("font")) {
    c.innerHTML = "<font  color='" + partC + "'>" + part + "</font> Otro texto en negro " + text;
  }
}
```

```css
#mm {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="goes" onclick="go()">
<div id="mm" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Edicion, esos metodos no me sirven

Comment: @EduardoSebastian ¿por qué? .-.

Comment: Ya edite porqué no me sirve

Comment: @EduardoSebastian solo quieres una parte del string con ese formato? En un `input` es *todo o nada*

Comment: Osea es imposible según tu?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian según yo no, segun los creadores. así lo quieres?

Comment: Mmm, vale me podrías dar algo de documentación para investigar? porfavor

Comment: @lois6b en vez de "Otro texto en negro" puedes poner también `&nbsp;` es un espacio y puede escribir en negro

Comment: @JuankGlezz si, era para que se viera visualmente que no todo ha de ser rojo

Comment: @EduardoSebastian documentacion? busca "etiqueta input". ahi tienes toda la informacion. Edité la respuesta